# How can I build on top of someone else's map? I want to get their layer

Tags: dictionary, leaflet, openstreetmap

Mapping novice here! I work for a humanitarian organization and we want to take a map that was built using leaflet and OSM and then build on top of it (basically adding our own location markers).

It seems like a government took OSM, then added their own admin boundaries layer on top of it.  What we want to do it copy their boundary layer and then add GPS points.

If this is possible, please let me kno and feel free to DM me!

So far I have tried to open the map, I've also reached out to a friend at OSM and tried to message the leaflet team on twitter (though saw it was blocked).

I also have been going through the documentation on how to use leaflet but since this is time-critical task I wanted to check here.

Comment: Ask the people who made that map.

Comment: Is this about https://twitter.com/itranslate123/status/1730628993399820783 ?